# returns undefined with all variables right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I was making a 'Help' page with some javascript when an error came and I don't know why this is happening because I've already done it the same way and worked right.

my error occurs when I enter `help` on the input and press the submit button, it shows me an alert telling me [Object object]. **I'm trying to print the very first `"help"` string on `help variable`**.

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3u272/

here is the code

```
//  Toda la ayuda esta guardada en esta cadena de variables
var help = {
    "help" : {
        title : "help",
        description : "Utiliza help mas una de las funciones de a continuación.",
    },
};


//  Funcion para mostrar la ayuda
var ayudaSubmit = document.form.buscar;
$(ayudaSubmit).on("click", function () {
    var helpInputVal = document.form.ayuda.value,
        helpQuestion = help[helpInputVal];
    if (!helpQuestion) {
        alert(helpInputVal + " MEEEEEH!");
    } else {
        alert(helpQuestion);
    };
});
```

and here the HTML

```
<form name="form">
    <input name="ayuda" type="text" placeholder="help with + la funci&oacute;n" id="helpInput"/>
    <input name="buscar" type="submit" placeholder="Buscar" value="Buscar" id="ayudaSubmit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `[object Object]` is the string representation of an object. Can you post a demo here http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce the issue? Use the console to debug your code, not `alert`.

Comment: `alert(helpQuestion.description);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are alerting the entire object. You may want to alert only the message instead:
Change your second `alert()` in:

```
alert(helpQuestion.description);
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are printing out the whole object. If you only want to print out the text you should do:

```
alert(helpQuestion.description);
```

And a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rLFvM/